# Counting Attendance Per Student

Tags: sql, oracle

Software: PowerSchool (Oracle database) Education software

When I run the sql for one student the attendance count in correct.  When I add addition students the count becomes the total from all the students, and that total is listed for each student.  How do I reset the count after each student or does the subquery go in a different location?  Any suggestions appreciated. ~Liz

```
SELECT s.DCID,
s.lastfirst, 
(SELECT COUNT(distinct att.ID) 
                       FROM Students s JOIN Attendance att ON         
s.id=att.studentid
                      JOIN  Attendance_code attc ON         
attc.id=att.attendance_codeID
                        WHERE  s.id=att.studentid 
                     AND s.id=5538
                   AND att.Att_Mode_Code='ATT_ModeDaily'
                    AND att.yearid=27
                  AND attc.Presence_Status_CD = ('Absent')) AS TAbs
FROM Students s  

WHERE  s.enroll_tatus=0
AND s.grade_level IN (6, 7, 8)
 AND s.id=5538
ORDER BY s.grade_level ASC, s.lastfirst ASC;
```

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT s.DCID,
s.lastfirst, 
(SELECT COUNT(distinct att.ID) 
                       FROM Students s JOIN Attendance att ON         
s.id=att.studentid
                      JOIN  Attendance_code attc ON         
attc.id=att.attendance_codeID
                        WHERE  s.id=att.studentid 
                     AND s.id=5538
                   AND att.Att_Mode_Code='ATT_ModeDaily'
                    AND att.yearid=27
                  AND attc.Presence_Status_CD = ('Absent')) AS TAbs
FROM Students s  

WHERE  s.enroll_tatus=0
AND s.grade_level IN (6, 7, 8)
 AND s.id=5538
GROUP BY s.DCID, s.lastfirst #You should add this line
ORDER BY s.grade_level ASC, s.lastfirst ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

3 things you should change:

- Remove both student's IDs filters. You want to see all students, not just the one with `ID 5538`.
- Use different alias for the same table! You are referencing the Students table twice, and both times with the same alias (`S`).
- Link the outmost `Student` table `ID` with the subquery's `Student` table `ID`, so each `COUNT(DISTINCT att.ID)` is calculated by student, and not overall.

Here is the edited query:

```
SELECT 
    s1.DCID,
    s1.lastfirst, 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(distinct att.ID) 
        FROM 
            Students s2 -- Use different alias!
            JOIN Attendance att ON s2.id=att.studentid
            JOIN  Attendance_code attc ON attc.id=att.attendance_codeID
        WHERE  
            att.Att_Mode_Code='ATT_ModeDaily' AND 
            att.yearid=27 AND 
            attc.Presence_Status_CD = ('Absent') AND
            s1.id = s2.id -- Relate both Student tables
    ) AS TAbs
FROM 
    Students s1  
WHERE  
    s1.enroll_tatus=0 AND 
    s1.grade_level IN (6, 7, 8) 
ORDER BY 
    s1.grade_level ASC, 
    s1.lastfirst ASC;
```

Comment: Ezequiel, This fixed, and it makes sense.  On to the tardy total!  Have a GREAT weekend.